# Can’t scrape website Error running your code. TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded

Tags: puppeteer

I am tying to scrape a local website('https://nieis.namibiaatwork.gov.na/') it it just keeps on timing out 'Error running your code. TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded' all other websites are being scraped with no problem.

I tried ignoring bad certificates using:

```
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [
        "--proxy-server='direct://'",
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
        '--enable-features=NetworkService'
      ]
    });
```

but all I get is a 'Error running your code. SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'.

I also tried forcing the website to wait until the entire page has loaded:

await page.goto('https://nieis.namibiaatwork.gov.na', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});

but all I get is 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'.

I am using https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/ to test the website **scraping** before I implement the code on my live server.

are there some websites that cannot be **scraped** or is there another library I can use to **scrape** the above website any information that would help me **scrape** this website would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can not open https://nieis.namibiaatwork.gov.na/ in a common browser as well, it also times out.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Comment: Voting to close because this site appears to timeout for me too just trying to navigate to it in the browser, so I don't see there's anything actionable to be done here because it's not a puppeteer issue.